# Drupal commerce products performance when switching between many variations

Tags: commerce

In my website I have around 5000 products and 40 products variations (like, color, size, type taxonomy etc). A single product display (node) may contain 1200 to 1800 products. When switching between the product variations, the page takes around 28 to 35 seconds to output the results. I tried commerce_entitycache module. But it doesn't help. Is there any tricks to improve the performance in this situation?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: 1800 product variations on a single page? Wow. You need to either get a much better server to host your site on, or, and this would be the far better idea: re-think your approach to products completely. You haven't described your requirements, but there's almost certainly a better way to do this. 1800 variations for any product is getting towards the realms of insanity; Commerce almost certainly wasn't built with those sorts of figures in mind

Comment: Please read the question once again.. I have only 40 variations.

Comment: Ok...so what does _A single product display (node) may contain 1200 to 1800 products._ mean? Would that not be 1800x40 then, which would be much worse? 1800 of anything on any one page is going to cause you problems. Just use the network tab to check out the size of the response from the ajax call, that should give you a hint as to the magnitude of the problem. After that the browser has to render 1800 products in one go. You should expect to see the UI loop freeze for that unless the client machine is particularly powerful

Comment: Okay.. If this cause the performance problem, what will be the solution? How do I proceed further                                                                       ?Thanks.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't proceed with this, I'd find a different way to categorise and display products. One that ensures a maximum of, say, 10 products on any one page. I think you're fighting a losing battle trying to get 1800 products onto a single page